# Understanding module argument modification in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

If I do the following in Mathematica

```
f[l_] := Module[{}, l[[1]] = Append[l[[1]], 3]; l]
f[{{}, 3}]
```

I get an error:

```
Set::setps: "{{},3} in the part assignment is not a symbol. "
```

Even `l={{}, 3};f[l]` gets the same error. But I can do `f[l_] := Module[{}, {Append[l[[1]], 3],l[[2]]}]` or `l = {{}, 3}; l[[1]] = Append[l[[1]], 3]; l`.

What is your explanation?

Comment: I discussed this topic at length in my book, specifically here: http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node382.html, and here: http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node207.html

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: oh, let me have a look. Thanks for the references. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple problems here:

1. Attempting Part assignment on a non-Symbol, just as the error message states.
2. Attempting to manipulate a named replacement object as though it were a symbol.

The replacement that takes place in this construct:

```
f[x_] := head[x, 2, 3]
```

Is analogous to that of `With`:

```
With[{x = something}, head[x, 2, 3]]
```

That is, the substitution is made directly and before evaluation, such that the function `Head` never even sees an object `x`.  Look what happens with this:

```
ClearAll[f,x]
x = 5;
f[x_] := (x = x+2; x)

f[x]
```

```
During evaluation of In[8]:= Set::setraw: Cannot assign to raw object 5. >>

Out[]= 5
```

This evaluates as: `(5 = 5+2; 5)` so not only is assignment to `5` impossible, but all instances of `x` that appear in the right hand side of `:=` are replaced with the value of x when it is fed to `f`.  Consider what happens if we try to bypass the assignment problem by using a function with side effects:

```
ClearAll[f, x, incrementX]

incrementX[] := (x += 2)
x = 3;
incrementX[];
x
```

```
5
```

So our `incrementX` function is working.  But now we try:

```
f[x_] := (incrementX[]; x)

f[x]
```

```
5
```

`incrementX` did not fail:

```
x
```

```
7
```

Rather, the the value of `x` was `5` at the time of evaluation of `f[x]` and therefore that is returned.

---

### What does work?

What options do we have for things related to what you are attempting?  There are several.

#### 1. Use a Hold attribute

We can set a Hold attribute such as `HoldFirst` or `HoldAll` on the function, so that we may pass the symbol name to RHS functions, rather than only its value.

```
ClearAll[heldF]
SetAttributes[heldF, HoldAll]

x = {1, 2, 3};

heldF[x_] := (x[[1]] = 7; x)

heldF[x]
x
<pre>{7, 2, 3}</pre>
<pre>{7, 2, 3}</pre>
```

We see that both the global value of `x`, and the `x` expression returned by `heldF` are changed.  Note that `heldF` must be given a Symbol as an argument otherwise you are again attempting `{1, 2, 3}[[1]] = 7`.

#### 2. Use a temporary Symbol

As Arnoud Buzing shows, we can also use a temporary Symbol in `Module`.

```
ClearAll[proxyF]

x = {1, 2, 3};

proxyF[x_] := Module[{proxy = x}, proxy[[1]] = 7; proxy]

proxyF[x]
proxyF[{1, 2, 3}]
x
```

```
{7, 2, 3}
```

```
{7, 2, 3}
```

```
{1, 2, 3}
```

#### 3. Use ReplacePart

We can also avoid symbols completely and just use `ReplacePart`:

```
ClearAll[directF]

x = {1, 2, 3};

directF[x_] := ReplacePart[x, 1 -> 7]

directF[x]
x
```

```
{7, 2, 3}
```

```
{1, 2, 3}
```

This can be used for modifications rather than outright replacements as well:

```
ClearAll[f]

f[l_] := ReplacePart[l, 1 :> l[[1]] ~Append~ 3]

f[{{}, 3}]
```

```
{{3}, 3}
```

Comment: Thank you for the complete and thorough explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
f[{{}, 3}] // Trace
```

and you see that the value of `l` is inserted into the `l[[1]] = Append[l[[1]], 3]` bit before evaluation. So mma is attempting to evaluate this: `{{}, 3}[[1]] = {3}`

This may do something like you want

```
ClearAll[f];
f[l_] := Module[{},
  Append[l[[1]], 3]~Join~Rest[l]
  ]
```

(the idea is to avoid assigning to parts of `l`, since `l` will be evaluated before the assignment is attempted)

Answer (score 1):

If you do want to use Part in your Module, you may want to consider using a temporary variable:

```
f[l_List] := Module[{t = l}, t[[1]] = Pi; t]
```

And:

```
In[] := f[{1, 2, 3}]

Out[] = {Pi, 2, 3}
```